# FacebookFeed October CMS plugin return errors

Tags: octobercms, facebook-instant-articles, octobercms-plugins, facebook-feed

The message I got "could not authorize request. please check your facebook AppID, page id and secret!". How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you double checked you Facebook API credentials?

Comment: seem plugin doesn't work properly.

Comment: Said plugin uses version 4.x of Facebook's PHP API. It's been deprecated for a while and seems to have stopped working. Migrating it to version 5.x is quite the chore.